# JIT-ing on FPGAs?

Tags: jit, fpga

Many VMS, JVM/LLVM/... have JITs -- as the code is being interpreted, x86 instructions are created on the fly and executed.

If there something similar to this for FPGAS? Is there someway where as an FPGA is *running*, I reconfigure it? [If so, please provide project / paper links. If not, what is the technology bottleneck that prevents this from happening?]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there someway where as an FPGA is
>   running, I reconfigure it?

"partial reconfiguration" may be the phrase to Google for.

Answer (score 1):

The main place this sort of thing is done is in high-end routers and switches.  The biggest Cisco and Juniper routers are basically big boards full of FPGAs and PHYs to do the routing, along with a big server to run the routing protocols and compile the tables into the FPGAs.  Normally they do this by keeping some portion of the FPGA resources spare to take a new chunk of table processor, and hot-swapping it in once the programming is completed; then the old section can be taken out of service to serve as the next spare.

Comment: I believe that they have now a lot of customized ASICs instead of FPGAs, but still the FPGA play major role in comm.